# custom jquery or javascript remove special characters from a string extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to do this:

```
var test = "A3%2345-S63.][343\g30.1.0.45";
test.removeSpecialCharacters();
```

all special characters ie (%,*, (,[..etc) will be removed);

or

```
test.removeSpecialCharacters("-");
```

meaning all special characters will be replaced with "-"

I've tried with this but i don't think i'm doing it right :(

```
jQuery.fn.removeSpecialCharacters = function (optional replaceWith) {
    this.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');
}
```

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this?

Comment: jquery elements are not strings, your extension makes sense as a string prototype, not a jquery extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use jQuery for this. Adding the function to `jQuery.fn` would make it a method usable on jQuery objects. However, you want it for strings. They are instances of `String` so you need to extend `String.prototype` instead:

```
String.prototype.removeSpecialChars = function(replaceWith) {
    return this.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, replaceWith || '');
}
```